# How to compute features using DAISY feature extractor?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, feature-detection, feature-extraction, object-recognition

I am wondering if somebody has used DAISY features for object recognition problems?

Link to DAISY (MATLAB one) is: http://cvlab.epfl.ch/software/daisy

My question is how to use this software (MATLAB) to get keypoints and their descriptors? I can found out the descriptors (in *dzy.descs*), however I cannot found keypoints.

I want to give a try to this technique for object recognition, since, it has been written that it is computation fast and produce better result.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DAISY is designed for **dense** point matching, which means it computes a descriptor for every pixel in the image - that's what it is designed to do.  You *could* just retrieve the features for particular pixels in the image using the `display_descriptor` function as described in the documentation:

```
out = display_descriptor(dzy,y,x);
```

where `x` and `y` are the pixel co-ordinates.  You could then use a keypoint detector of your own (e.g. corners, blobs, SIFT keypoints - see [Blob Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection) on Wikipedia) to decide which features to extract.  You should bear in mind however that this is not the intended use of DAISY.